# SQL Server Database Recovery

Tags: sql-server

do u have any idea , which is the best software or best way to recover corrupt database in sql 2000/2005/2008

Answer (score 6):

### The backup tool.

Seriously. if you have corrupt data, it is corrupt...

It cannot be recovered from the DB file - go back to your latest backup, apply it, roll forward the transaction logs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run Run DBCC checkdb with repair_allow_data_loss. if it doesn't provide any suitable result then try to restore database from last backup. otherwise the Free SQL .mdf recovery software is best option for recovering the database see here: http://www.mdfviewer.com/recovery/